# Having problem while using multi-block module with my custom module

Tags: blocks, hooks

I have created a custom module which add a block to list posts from a specific content type.There is a drop down in attached image named "Content types"

[image]

When I am trying to create multiple instance of this block using multi-block module.It takes last created instance value for content types field means value is same for every inatance .Is there any way to create different instance for different content type?

Should I provide the code which I have written?